# Why am I getting the Tomcat error "HTTP Status 404 - The requested resource is not available."?

Tags: jsp, tomcat, servlets

Here is what is going on. Whenever I create a servlet on my laptop in NetBeans and deploy it locally, the servlet works perfectly. However, when I deploy the very same WAR file to my server (Apache Tomcat/6.0.36) over the network via the Manager app, I will always get this error. Whenever I attempt to access any .html or .jsp files included in the servlet, they work fine. However, whenever I attempt to access any of the servlets (the .class files), I always get this error. I am not using a web.xml, so I do not believe this can be the issue. I have hot deployed locally through NetBeans and also locally through the Manager app, and they both work. It only seems to be when I try to deploy this WAR through the Manager app to a different system.

Thanks for taking the time to read. Have a great day. :-)

Comment: "I am not using a web.xml": perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: I was under the impression that a web.xml was not necessary when using servlets version 2.0 and later.

Comment: To access a Servlet you should map the Servlet class in Web.xml corresponding to the Url pattern.

Comment: Again, I was under the impression the file wasn't needed for servlet versions 2.0 and greater.

Comment: What's the server/version that Netbeans uses locally? It might just be the difference between Tomcat 6 and 7. Also it might help to know what you use instead of web.xml, and if you're not having one at all, or if it's just more-or-less empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Tomcat 7 with Servlet 3 support if you want to use annotations.